# How to write a delete statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to write a delete query. Below is what I already came up with however I'm not sure if its correct and I worried that I might delete something that I shouldn't.

```
    Delete from TABLE1
where DATE = 202002
```

This table contains 5 fields and I need all of the data to be deleted form this table only for this DATE that I have listed. I was also thinking of writing it this way (example below) and wasnt sure which one of the two is correct.

```
Delete field1, field2, field3, field4 field5 from TABLE1
where DATE = 202002
```

Please advise.

PS. I'm working in Test environment.

Comment: The first very is mostly correct, but what is the type of your `Date` column, and also what is your database?

Comment: not sure what you mean by what type of date column it is. The format that I listed the date is the way it is in the field. Also its an oracle database.

Comment: How is your `DATE` column defined in the `CREATE TABLE` statement? What data-type is it?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: DELETE is to delete an entry (or entries depending on your condition), but I think what you need is just UPDATE to clear values on certain field(s). In order to clear those values, you have to know the type and expected default value for each field.

Comment: Field1 (IDate_ID) = NUMBER (6), Field2 (ID_Field) = VARCHAR2 (20 byte), Field3 = Number (14,10) Field4 (Date_Field)  = DATE, Field5 = VARCHAR2 (10 byte)....Please note that the "Date" of 202002 that I mentioned is from Field1 with the data type of Number (6)

Comment: My coworker and I had already ran a delete statement on this exact table and fields before and it gave me the results that I wanted. I remember it being a really simple query however I'm not sure where the note is that I made but I'm pretty sure it was a delete function that we used

Comment: "where date = ", is invalid itself, because it is saying 'where the column named 'date' equals ...', and 'date' is a reserved word, so cannot be a column name.

Comment: Beyond that since you later identify it as 'date_field' (legal, but still looks like not the real name) and is of type DATE, you then compare it to a number.  This forces oracle to convert the number to a date, which may or may not work the way you expect.  And keep in mind that oracle DATE types always include time, to the second. So assuming 202002 represents Feb of 2020, you still have to account for day and time in your comparison.  I strongly suspect that you are not deleting what you think you are. If you _are_ getting expected result, it's pure luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first form is correct:

```
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE
  WHERE SOME_FIELD = 'SOME VALUE'
```

You can't put field names after `DELETE` because you're deleting an entire row, not just a few fields.

Comment: `The first form is correct` ... not if that's a date column

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - the general form (`DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE <condition>`) is correct, which is why in the example shown I specifically used a column name other than `DATE` and a value which appears to be a number. `DATE` as a column name brings to mind...CTHULHU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :-)

Comment: do I have to "commit" once the delete statement is ran?

Comment: My first query worked. Thank you guys for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here are unclear, so let's start with the basics.

First, a delete query will delete records (rows) of information in which 0 or more conditions are met.  If your date field is indeed integer-based, then the first query you wrote will work fine.

Your second statement will not work because delete statements work on records rather than columns.  If you wanted to keep the record but eliminate the individual field data you could do something like this (note this is T-SQL syntax, but is likely close to Oracle's):

```
Update Table1 set
Field1 = Null,
Field2 = Null,
Field3 = Null,
Field4 = Null,
Field5 = Null
where 
Date = 202002
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UPDATE sentence instead DELETE (that delete data rows don't data columns) like:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET 
field1 = NULL, field2 = NULL, field3 = NULL, field4 = NULL, field5 = NULL 
WHERE DATE = 202002
```